# Switch direction of association between objects

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Say I have a class `foo`:

```
class foo {
    String someString;
    List<String> someList;
}
```

If I have a list of `foo`'s, is there a way for me to create a new list/array/whatever of `foo`'s with essentially the `someString` and `someList` values remapped? For example:

```
arr1: [
    foo {
        someString: 'test1',
        someList: ['a', 'b']
    },
    foo {
        someString: 'test2',
        someList: ['b', 'c']
    }
]
```

Would become

```
arr2: [
    foo {
        someString: 'a',
        someList: ['test1']
    },
    foo {
        someString: 'b',
        someList: ['test1', 'test2']
    },
    foo {
        someString: 'c',
        someList: ['test2']
    },
]
```

Right now, I have a nested loop that iterates over each element of `someList` for each foo and compiles them into a map where the key is the `someList` value and the value is a set of the `someString` values that have come from foos where the `someList` value was present. Then do a map of the entry set to convert it to new foos with the key and value passed as constructor params.

```
Map<String, Set<String>> myMap;

for(foo f : arr1) {
    for(String s : f.someList) {
        Set<String> mySet = myMap.get(s);
        if(mySet == null) {
            myMap.put(s, new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(f.someString)));
        } else {
            mySet.add(f.someString);
        }
    }
}

List<String> myNewList = myMap.entrySet()
                              .stream()
                              .map(e -> 
                                    new foo(e.key, new ArrayList<String>(e.value)))
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It seems to work fine, but it's not the prettiest in the world, so I was wondering if there's another approach to doing this.

Comment: Few points in general. 1. Your final output in the `map` currently is not a `List<String>`, its a `Set`. 2. Your initialization of a `Set` wouldn't work that way unless you end up creating your own implementation of the interface. 3. Initializing `Set<String> mySet = myMap.get(s);` for every string in someList also doesn't make sense for the output you're looking to obtain.

Comment: The examples are pseudo-code in some spots where the actual way to do it is rather verbose. Probably should have specified that in the initial question. My thinking re 3 is that there needs to be the null check, and initializing the set saves having to retrieve from the map in both the if and the add in the else.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you mean. Just do a contains key check instead of the actual init.

Comment: Edited example to use the actual syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First flip your objects by using a map:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
arr1.forEach(foo -> 
        foo.someList.forEach(s -> 
                map.computeIfAbsent(
                    s, 
                    k -> new LinkedHashSet<>())
                .add(foo.someString)));
```

Then create the `foo` objects from the map:

```
List<foo> result = new ArrayList<>();
map.forEach((k, v) -> list.add(new foo(k, new ArrayList<>(v))));
```

This assumes you have the appropriate constructor.

Comment: Just to add to clarify, then that *appropriate constructor* shall convert the `Set` of Strings into `List` as expected in the object to be.

Comment: This is great, thanks! This might be a dumb question. Is LinkedHashSet just to maintain order or is there some additional reason to use it?

Comment: @AndrewRobie Just to maintain insertion order.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create the foo objects in your nested loop like this?

```
Map<String, foo> myMap;

 for(foo f : arr1) {
  for(String s : f.someList) {
    foo myFoo= myMap.get(s);
    if(mySet == null) {
        myFoo= new foo(s, new ArrayList<String>);
        myMap.put(s, myFoo);

    } 
    myFoo.somelist.add(f.someString);
  }
}
```

Comment: Basically duplication within someList. In an ideal world, I'd just switch it to a set, but that's off the table so I figured converting a set to a list at the end was better than iterating over foo.someList every pass.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample on java 8 with Guava library:

```
private static Function<Foo,Set<Foo>> fooStream(final Map<String,Foo> map){
        return foo -> foo.getSomeList().stream()
                .map(createNewFoo(foo.getSomeString(),map)).collect(Collectors.toSet());

    }

    private static Function<String,Foo> createNewFoo(final String someString,final Map<String,Foo> map){
        return s->{
            if(Objects.nonNull(map.get(s))){
                map.get(s).getSomeList().add(someString);
                return map.get(s);
            }
            return createNewFoo(s,someString,map);
        };
    }

    private static Foo createNewFoo(final String someListValue , final String someString,final Map<String,Foo> map){
        final Foo foo = new Foo(someListValue,Lists.newArrayList(someString));
        map.put(someListValue,foo);
        return foo;
    }
```

And here how you can call it in main method :

```
final Map<String, Foo> myMap = Maps.newHashMap(); 
final Foo foo1 = new Foo("test1",Arrays.asList("A","B")); 
final Foo foo2 = new Foo("test2",Arrays.asList("B","C")); 
final List<Foo> foos = Arrays.asList(foo1,foo2); 
final Set<Foo> fooSet = foos.stream()
.map(fooStream(myMap)) 
.flatMap(Set::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Where Foo class is :

```
public class Foo {
    private String someString;
    private List<String> someList;

    public Foo(String someString, List<String> someList) {
        this.someString = someString;
        this.someList = someList;
    }
//getters and setters
}
```